# Filemaker -- how to show sub summary across more than one page

Tags: layout, filemaker

Beginner filemake rquestion.  I'm setting up a layout to tell me how many photo call and other data related to a particular client.  So I have a sub summary which shows the client name, and phone call data the body.

The problem is that when the data spills over to another page, the sub summary with the client name disappears, so you have to keep flipping back a page (or sometimes two pages) to see which client the data relates to.

It seems like this should be simple, but for some reason I can't seem to get it to work. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the client name in the header part and hide it conditionally when the first record on the page belongs to a client different from the previous record.